# How is this ammeter connected in this diagram?

Tags: schematics, symbol, diagram

What are the `k`, `i` and circle symbols in the red area on this single line diagram?

I feel like the ammeter symbol was deported to the right to align it with the 4 light indicators. Is that right?

[image]

Comment: Could be a current clamp?

Comment: I have no way to go and check physically I must say btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the symbol for a CT (Current Transformer) clamp.

[image]

[image source](https://gallery.proficad.com/symbols/electrical-installations/outdoor-installations/transformers/current-transformer/current-transformer.html)

The `12/1A` denotes the ratio of the transformer.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_transformer):

> CTs are specified by their current ratio from primary to secondary. [...] For example, a 4000:5 CT secondary winding will supply an output current of 5 amperes when the primary winding current is 4000 amperes

The letters are not `k` and `i` but `k` and `l` and denote the polarity of the clamp as explained [here](https://www.janitza.com/installation-of-current-transformers.html):

> The connections of the primary winding are designated "K" and "L" or "P1" and "P2", and the connections of the secondary winding are designated "k" and "l" or "S1" and "S2". The polarity must be established such that the "flow direction of the energy" runs from K to L.

Thanks @Drew for the heads-up.

Answer (score 4):

It's almost certainly a current transformer as per [this link](https://www.electrical-symbols.com/electrical-electronics-pdf/Single-Line_Transformers_Symbols.pdf): -

[image]

I think the 12/1A part implies a 1:12 turns ratio too.